# Need help understanding optimization for Navigation Links - Swift UI

Tags: arrays, swiftui, navigation, refactoring, swiftui-navigationlink

I'm having a hard time getting my head around NavigationLinks. I currently have a list array and several other arrays for Regions, but I'm stumped on how could I plug this into a List and have it show me the data related to that specific Region. I have gotten it to work by using separate views for each 'Shrine' variable, but that seems so unoptimized.

```
struct Shrine: Identifiable {
    var id: String
    let imageName: String
    let title: String
    let shrinenum: Int
    let location: String
    let puzzle: String
    let url: URL
    var isCompleted: Bool
    
}

struct ShrineList {
@State static var Akkala = [

// Here I have the data for the shrines in this Region


]

@State static var CentralHyrule = [

// Here I have the data for the shrines in this Region


]
}
```

Here is the View for when the Region is selected I need this list to link to each of the 'Shrine' variables and show the data I have on the following view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct RegionViewOpt: View {
    @StateObject var completed = Favorites()
    @State private var regionlist: [Region] = RegionList.regions
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            List(regionlist,id: \.id) { region in
                NavigationLink(destination: AkkalaListView(alldata: ShrineList.Akkala), label: {
                    
                    VStack{
                        ZStack{
                            Image(region.regionImage)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .frame(width: 420.0, height: 100)
                            Color.black
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .frame(width: 400.0, height: 100)
                                .opacity(0.1)
                            
                            
                            HStack(spacing: 2){
                                VStack(alignment:.leading, spacing: 1){
                                    Text(region.regionName)
                                        .font(.system(size: 25,weight: .bold))
                                        .lineLimit(1)
                                        .minimumScaleFactor(0.8)
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                        .shadow(radius: 2)
                                    
                                    Text("\(region.shrineAmount) Shrines")
                                        .font(.system(size: 12,weight: .medium))
                                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                                }
                                .padding(.leading,40)
                                Spacer()
                            }
                        }
                        Spacer()
                        
                    }
                    
                })
                
                
                .listRowSeparator(.hidden)
            }
            
            .navigationTitle("Regions")
            
        }
        .environmentObject(completed)
    }
        
}
```

I was also going to refactor the above list of cells, but the data passing has me stumped as well.

I appreciate any help I can get.
Thanks!

Comment: An observation: do not use `@State` in your `struct ShrineList`,
 `@State` is only for use inside a View. Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example  In particular show the code of `AkkalaListView` and what you want to do there.

Comment: State wrapped variables can’t be static variables. State can only be used in SwiftUI views. You should try the Apple SwiftUI tutorials.